# Syntax error using this symbol => in jquery while open in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, syntax

I have the following line of `javascript` code

```
let isTextNode = (_, el) => el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
```

The above works well in all the other browser apart from IE. IE complains about Syntax error at `=>`.

Can someone tell me how to get around this in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is not supported in the IE browser.
You could try to use the [Babel's translator](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAlgzgKiAHmAcgewCYggXggCgH0AaCEYASlwD4zgA6AO0xDgE8AHbHHidLenACiADTiEUAeQAiQgNxA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=) to translate the code, the result like this:

```
"use strict";

var isTextNode = function isTextNode(_, el) {
  return el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
};
```